# Solve $\iiint_B r^2\rho \ dV$, where $B$ is a cylinder not centered at the origin

Tags: integration

> Let $K$ be a homogenous body (i.e. it has a constant density $\rho$) that is bounded by the planes $z^2 = 2x, z = 0, x^2+y^2=x$. Find the moment of inertia regarding the $z$-axis.

Based on the lecture I suppose that I should compute

$$\iiint\limits_B  r^2\rho \ dV.$$

This means we have to compute the integral

$$\int_{z_1}^{z_2} \int_{y_1(z)}^{y_2(z)} \int_{x_1(y,z)}^{x_2(y,z)} f(x,y,z)\ dx \ dy \ dz$$

It can be seen that $B$ corresponds to the cylinder 
$$\bigg\{(x,y,z) \ \bigg\lvert \ \bigg(x-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^2 +y^2 = \frac{1}{4}, \ 0 \le z \le \sqrt{2x} \ \bigg\}$$

Since the the cylinder is not centered in the origin I do not know how to transfer the integral into cylindrical coordinates. Could you help me?

Comment: The radios must be $\frac{1}{2}$, so  $\frac{1}{4}$ in the equation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *regular* cylinder coordinates $x = r \cos \theta$, $y = r \sin \theta$ and $z = z$. We have

$$
\Bigl(x - \frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^2 + y^2 \leq \frac14
\Rightarrow x^2 + y^2 \leq x
$$

I will leave the algebra details to you. This means that applying the coordinate transformation the domain satifies the restriction

$$r^2 \leq r \cos \theta \Rightarrow r \leq \cos \theta$$

Thus, since $r$ is positive we obtain the following bounds

$$
\begin{align}
0 \, &\leq r \leq \cos \theta \\
-\frac{\pi}{2} & \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \\
0 \, & \leq z \leq \sqrt{2 r \cos \theta}
\end{align}
$$

The restrictions on $\theta$ were again obtained from the fact that $r$ is positive, thus $\cos \theta$ needs to be positive as well. 
Similarly the bounds on $z$ were derived from $0 \leq z \leq \sqrt{2x}$ and $x = r \cos \theta$.

The moment of inertia is calculated by using:
$$ I = \iiint\limits _B \rho(x,y,z)\,\bar{r}^2\,\mathrm{d}V, $$ where $\bar{r}$ is the distance from the rotation axis. When you change to cylindrical Coordinates you need to take into account that:
$$ \mathrm{d}V = r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}z$$
And the distance from the rotation axis is:
$$ \bar{r}=\sqrt{y^2+z^2}= \sqrt{r^2\sin^2(\theta)+z^2}$$
With $\rho(x,y,z)=\rho$ you get:

$$
\iiint\limits_B  r^2\rho \ \mathrm{d}V
=
\rho \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\cos \theta} \int_0^{\sqrt{2 r \cos \theta}} \bigl(r^2\sin^2(\theta)+z^2\bigr) \cdot r \, \mathrm{d}z \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta
$$

Where the rest is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to find moment of inertia about the z-axis, $r$ would represent the distance from the point to the z-axis, i.e

$$r = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$$

Hence, the integral would be

$$\int\int\int_B (x^2+y^2)\rho dV$$

$$= \int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{x(1-x)}}^{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\int_0^{\sqrt {2x}}(x^2+y^2)dzdydx$$